# Using class functions as arguments in methods NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use a class function as an argument in another methods. But I keep on getting function not defined when trying to do so. Below is how my class looks like:

```
class Test{
constructor(name){
this.name = name;
    }

functionA(){
    console.log('My name is John');
    }

functionB(){
    console.log('My name is Steve');
    }

}


function caller(args){
    let test = new Test('t1');
  return test.args;
}

caller(functionA())
```

I am not sure what to do here. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the *function name* (as a string).  Currently you are *calling* `functionA()`, which is not a defined function.

See the below altered code:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  functionA() {
    console.log('My name is John');
  }

  functionB() {
    console.log('My name is Steve');
  }

}


function caller(args) {
  let test = new Test('t1');
  // use bracket notation to CALL the function, and include the () to call
  return test[args]();
}

// pass the function name as a string
caller('functionA')
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer, just an explanation.)

There's no top-level `functionA`, there's `functionA` defined inside `Test`. It's an instance method, so it's not even visible in the namespace of `Test` (`Test.functionA` is undefined).

In any case, you'd need to pass `functionA` (a reference to the function), not `functionA()` (a reference to the result that calling the function produces).

The cleanest method is indeed what @cale_b suggests.